# Problema con firebase-tools

Tags: firebase

Quiero actualizar el firebase, pero al actualizarlo y después pedir la version que tengo , es la misma.

```
firebase tools --version

sudo npm i -g firebase-tools to update
```

[image: MUESTA]

Comment: que tal si intentas ejecutar el comando sin sudo, y por favor agrega codigo a la respuesta

Comment: @JackNavaRow Igual ya lo ejecute de esa manera sin sudo , al ejecutarlo sin sudo , me marca error de acceso.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#update-cli , parece que tu problema viene por sudo

Comment: intenta `npm uninstall firebase-tools` intenta hacer `firebase tools --version` y su eso pasa probablemente lo instalaste local y no global

Comment: proba con sudo npm update -g firebase-tools